# How to list parent category and sub-category data with proper order

Tags: php, mysql

```
table : category  
    | id + category_name + parent_category_id |
    | 1  | Flower        |          0         |
    | 2  | Wall Decor    |          0         |
    | 3  | Stylish Living|          0         |
    | 4  | Mug           |          0         |
    | 5  | Sun Flower    |          1         |
    | 6  | Balsam        |          1         |
```

i try to list data with sort order parent category first and then sub-category.

```
Flower
flower > Sun Flower
flower > Balsam
Wall Decor
Stylish Living
Mug
```

as i try i can't get like above , below is what i get, flower > Sun Flower and flower > Balsam should under Flower .

```
Flower
Wall Decor
Stylish Living
Mug   
flower > Sun Flower
flower > Balsam
```

really appreciate if someone can give some idea or solution.

Comment: can you show your query?

Comment: please show your existing query that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT category
FROM (
  SELECT
     IF(p.category_name is null, c.category_name, CONCAT(p.category_name, ' > ', c.category_name)) AS 'category'
  FROM category c
  LEFT JOIN category p ON c.parent_category_id = p.category_id
) s
ORDER BY category
```

...is the best I can come up with for the results you want. [See it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5db9/8).

Comment: @ruslyrossi [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is the concatenation function, it simply joins strings together into one. Like `"String 1"."String 2"` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similiar structure, and use a variation of this:

```
SELECT
    p.category_id, p.category_name,
    c.category_id, c.category_name
FROM category AS c
JOIN category AS p ON (c.parent_category_id = p.category_id)    
ORDER BY p.category_name, c.category_name
```

You may have to tinker with the kind of JOIN you use (I know what should/should'nt have children), but it will give you all the children categories with their parents, sorted the way you've asked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to use `left join`, as parents won't have their own parents and will be filtered out during the join process

Comment: No doubt some filtering with WHERE's and JOINs variation is in order.  The snippet I copied from my code is quite a bit more extensive than this, so just simplified it as much as possible for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to display exactly what you're after.  Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT p.category_name as parent_category, '' as child_category
FROM category AS p
WHERE parent_category_id not in (select category_id from category)
UNION
SELECT p.category_name as parent_category, c.category_name as child_category
FROM category AS p
JOIN category AS c ON (c.parent_category_id = p.category_id)
ORDER BY parent_category, child_category
```

And here's the output:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| parent_category | child_category |
+-----------------+----------------+
| Flower          |                | 
| Flower          | Balsam         | 
| Flower          | Sun Flower     | 
| Mug             |                | 
| Stylish Living  |                | 
| Wall Decor      |                | 
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Note that this is only going to work for a 2-level parent-child relationship.  If you have third level and need to display it in three columns, then it gets a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to `GROUP BY category_name` as well as sorting.

This may also help you out quite a bit
http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Answer (score 0):

this is best answer to show list and sub list of category that has three column id,name,parent id

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$sql="select * from category where parent=0";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<ol>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<li >".$row['name']."</li>";
    abc($row['id']);
}

function abc($id)
{
    global $con;
    $sql="select * from category where parent=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<ol>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
        abc($row['id']);
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```

in this code we pass the parent id to function and function then call itself again to show the sub category